# Using JSF 2.0 Flash Scope problem

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm having trouble with a basic JSF 2.0 program! I'm trying to implement Flash scope, I've gotten the information carried over to the second page, but am now having trouble with referencing the flashed variables.

Here is my first page with its bean, this works fine:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Welcome to the JSF PoCs project</title>
 </h:head>
  <h:body>
   <h:form>
     <h1>Welcome to the JSF PoCs project</h1>
     <h:outputText value="Name: "/>
     <h:inputText id="txtName" value="#{registerBean.name}"/>
     <h:outputText value="EMail: "/>
     <h:inputText id="txtEMail"  value="#{registerBean.email}"/> 
     <h:commandButton value="register" action="#{registerBean.register}"/>
     <h:outputText></h:outputText>
    </h:form>
 </h:body>
</html>


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
@ManagedBean(name="registerBean")
public class RegisterBean {
private String name;
private String email;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String register() {

    JSFUtils.flashScope().put("registerBean", this);
    return "next";
}



}
```

This is where the problem is! It displays the correct data in the heading1 tags but does not set the next beans variable with the same data?

Now my question is, why does it work for a heading tag but not to set another beans variables?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
<h:head>
    <title>Welcome to the JSF PoCs project</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <c:set target="${confirmBean}" property="name" value="#    {flash.registerBean.name}"/>
        <c:set target="${confirmBean}" property="email"     value="${flash.registerBean.email}"/>
        <h1>Your User Name will be #{flash.registerBean.name} and email will be #    {flash.registerBean.email}</h1>
        <h:commandButton value="confirm" action="#{confirmBean.confirm}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name="confirmBean")
public class ConfirmBean {
     private String name;
     private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String confirm() {
    JSFUtils.flashScope().put("confirmBean", this);
    return "confirmPage";
}
```

}

After the button is pressed on the confirm.xhtml it directs to this page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Welcome to the JSF PoCs project</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    You have now registered with:  #{flash.confirmBean.name} and #    {flash.confirmBean.email}<br/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!!!!

Comment: hey do you get any solution with `@ViewScope` ??

Answer (score 3):

The JSTL `<c:set>` tags runs when the view is built, not when the view is rendered or restored. Thus, they are set in the `ConfirmBean` only in the request to display the form, not in the request to submit the form. Since the `ConfirmBean` is request scoped, all set values are lost.

I'd suggest to replace the whole Flash scope by just passing parameters.

```
<h:commandButton value="confirm" action="#{confirmBean.confirm}">
    <f:param name="name" value="#{registerBean.name}" />
    <f:param name="email" value="#{registerBean.email}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with the following in `ConfirmBean`:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.name}")
private String name;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.email}")
private String email;
```

Comment: this still doesn't work, there should be the info from value="#{flash.registerBean.name} and value="#{flash.registerBean.email}" on the next page, but it is blank. I works if I put something like value="Michael" but not like it currently is?

Comment: Hmm, I see. I updated the answer to take an alternative approach.

Comment: I still does not work...but don't worry I'm going to work with viewscope instead, thanks for your help!! :)